# 'str' object has no attribute 'relative_url'

Tags: django, django-forms, tags, django-templates, wagtail

I'm getting the error message 'str' object has no attribute 'relative_url' when loading a template tag in wagtail.

Here is my tag code:

```
from django import template
from home.models import *

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('home/subscribe_form.html')
def test_vdcristo():
    return {}
```

Here is my html template code:

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags  vdecristo_tags %}
```

```
    <form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="shop-subscribe bg-color-green margin-bottom-40">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 md-margin-bottom-20">
                            <h2>Subscribase para mantenerse<strong> informado</strong></h2>
                    </div>




                    <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="input-group">


                             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electronico..." {{ form.subscribase }}>
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></button>
                                    </span>

                            </div>

                                {{ form.subscribase.errors }}
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div><!--/end container-->
    </div>

 </form>
```

If I remove the line:

```
<form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST">
```

The form content loads, but of course it won't post.  Can someone help me figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is failing because your template code refers to the variables `page` and `form`, but you're not passing them from your tag code. (The error I'd expect to see here would be `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'relative_url'` - your error suggests that you're passing a string as the `page` variable.)

One possible way to make this work:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('home/subscribe_form.html')
def test_vdcristo():
    # Look up the relevant form page by slug; replace FormPage and 'subscribe-now'
    # as appropriate for your site
    page = FormPage.objects.get(slug='subscribe-now')
    return {
        'page': page,
        'form': page.get_form(),
    }
```

Comment: I'm now getting the error message KeyError at /radio/ 'request' when loading test_vdcristo tag. Any additional suggestion?

Comment: You'll probably need to retrieve the 'request' variable from the parent template's context - see the section about 'takes_context' on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags - and pass `'request': context['request']` in the list of variables you're returning.

Comment: passing the 'request': context['request'] fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should to use

```
{% url url_name %}
```

(notice: url, not pageurl) and have an url named *page* defined in urls.

Comment: This would be correct for Django in general, but in Wagtail `{% pageurl ... %}` is the appropriate tag to use when you want the URL corresponding to a Wagtail page object.